# How to update specific inputText in dataTable to be enabled or disabled based on rowSelect event

Tags: jsf, checkbox, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I need your help in updating a specific inputText component to be enabled in a dataTable once the checkbox in the row is ticked. Here is the code for the dataTable:

```
<h:form id="request">
      <p:dataTable value="#{dataTableView.employeeList}" id="Employee" var="emp"
                             selection="#{dataTableView.selectedEmployees}" rowKey="#{emp.id}">
      <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{dataTableView.EnableInputText}" />
      <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{dataTableView.EnableInputText}" />
             <p:columnGroup type="header">
               <p:row>
               <p:column/>
             <p:column headerText="ID"/>
             <p:column headerText="Name"/>
             <p:column headerText="Location"/>
             <p:column headerText="Remarks"/>
               </p:row>
              </p:columnGroup>
           <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%;text-align:center"/>
           <p:column headerText="ID">
           <h:outputText value="#{emp.id}"/>
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Name">
           <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}"/>
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Location">
           <h:outputText value="#{emp.location}"/>
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Remarks">
           <h:inputText id="inputT1" value="#{emp.remarks}" disabled="#{emp.disable}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

And the code in the backing bean:

```
private List<Student> employeeList = new ArrayList<Student>();
private List<Student> selectedEmployees;
private boolean disable=true;


public void EnableInputText(SelectEvent event) {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();


    for(int i=0;i<selectedEmployees.size();i++){ 
        for(int j=0;j<employeeList.size();j++){          
        if(selectedEmployees.get(i).getId().equals(employeeList.get(j).getId()))
        {
           selectedEmployees.get(j).setDisable(false);
            context.update("request:Employee:"+i+":inputT1");
           //employeeList.get(j).setDisable(false);
        }
       }
     }
}
```

Currently, I will be able to click on the checkbox  but the`inputText` will remain disabled and I will get the error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is more related to JAVA than the Primefaces.

The issue looks to be selectedEmployees.get(j).setDisable(false);

There is more chances of getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You just need to update the data table after the event trigger.

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"
                            listener="#{dataTableView.EnableInputText}" update="Employee" />
<p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                            listener="#{dataTableView.onRowSelect}" update="Employee"/>
 <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
                        listener="#{dataTableView.onRowUnselect}" update="Employee"/>
```

On checkbox select :

```
public void EnableInputText(SelectEvent event){
        for (int i = 0;i<selectedEmployees.size();i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j<employeeList.size();j++) {
                if (selectedEmployees.get(i).getId().equals(employeeList.get(j).getId())) {
                    employeeList.get(j).setDisabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On row select:

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent){
        Employee emp = (Employee)selectEvent.getObject();

        for (Employee e : employeeList) {
            if (emp.getId().equals(e.getId())) {
                e.setDisabled(false);
            }
            else {
                e.setDisabled(true);
            }
        }

    }
```

On Checkbox unselect

```
public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent unselectEvent){
        Employee emp = (Employee)unselectEvent.getObject();

        for (Employee e : employeeList) {
            if (emp.getId().equals(e.getId())) {
                e.setDisabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, unfortunately I will be able only to click on 1 checkbox in the page and the inputText will be enabled. However, when I try to click again on another checkbox or to uncheck the ticked one nothing will happen and the page seems to be freezed.

Comment: It looks to be working fine in my system. Do you have any error?

Comment: Yes copied and pasted, but still the issue is there

Comment: Any log you have on server side? Also Could you check you have any log in browser (Console)?

Comment: I am using only System.out.println to display any error in the console but it is a strange thing that nothing is printed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109988/discussion-between-unknown-and-99maas).